# search pdf links from all over the website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I want to search a website and look for all pdf links. I know there are several solutions with BeautifulSoup to look for pdf files using < a > tags but I want to search the whole domain using the base url, instead of just the page linked.

My idea was to a) first search a whole website for all sub links and then b) filter out the links that have a .pdf extension. For the first part, I tried this https://github.com/mujeebishaque/extract-urls:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    user_input_url = "https://www.aurednik.de/"
    
    if not user_input_url or len(user_input_url) < 1:
        raise Exception("INFO: Invalid Input")

    _start = user_input_url.find('//')
    _end   = user_input_url.find('.com')

    readable_website_name = user_input_url[_start+2:_end].strip()
    
    try:
        website_content = requests.get(user_input_url.strip()).text
    except:
        check_internet = requests.get('https://google.com').status_code
        
        if check_internet != requests.codes.ok:
            raise ConnectionError("ERROR: Check internet connection.")
    
    _soup = BeautifulSoup(website_content, features='lxml')
    
    internal_url_links = []
    external_url_links = []
    
    for link in _soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        if readable_website_name in link.get('href'):
            internal_url_links.append(link['href'])
        
        if readable_website_name not in link.get('href') and len(link.get('href')) > 3:
            external_url_links.append(link['href'])
    
    print(internal_url_links, '\n')
    print(external_url_links, '\n')
```

I was expecting that it would be able to crawl and return all links such as
https://www.aurednik.de/info-service/downloads/#unserekataloge

and https://www.aurednik.de/downloads/AUREDNIK_Haupt2021.pdf
but that is not the case. I dont see the 2nd pdf link at all and for the first link, I only see

```
/info-service/downloads/#unserekataloge
```

when I print out the external links. I want the full link and preferably also all pdf links on the website domain. How else could I achieve this? I am open to using any tools or libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the website has dynamic content. Check if the HTML loaded by BeautifulSoup contains is the same as when you inspect the website in your browser. If not use for example selenium to scrape the website with dynamically loaded content.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

internal_url_links = []
external_url_links = []
  
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if readable_website_name in link.get('href'):
        internal_url_links.append(link['href'])
        
    if readable_website_name not in link.get('href') and len(link.get('href')) > 3:
        external_url_links.append(link['href'])
    
print(internal_url_links, '\n')
print(external_url_links, '\n')
driver.close()
```

Comment: where do we add the original base url here?